# Visual Studio 2015 Python 3.5 debug startup error

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, quantlib-swig

#### Python 3.5 debug startup error

I tried to start a small Python program in DEBUG mode using Visual Studio 2005. But it fails to get to the first statement which is an `import` statement. Why does it get a `__file__` error as described below?

A Quantlib example called Swap.py runs without error in Visual Studio 2015 in release mode. But in debug mode it gets this error on startup:

```
Additional information: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

The Quantlib version is 1.6.2 and the QuantLib SWIG version is 1.6.1.

This is the first line of swap.py is, and it does not get that far:

```
from QuantLib import *
```

I installed Python 3.5 debug components.

Then in Visual Studio 2015 for Python, I created a Python Environment to use python_d.exe, pythonw_d.exe, and python35_d.dll.

Output Window:

```
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\python_d.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\python35_d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.    <frozen importlib._bootstrap>!_spec_from_module Line 483 Python
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>!_setup Line 1107           Python
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>!_install Line 1134     Python
[External Code]
python_d.exe!wmain(int argc, wchar_t * * argv) Line 14     C
[External Code]
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\ProgramFiles\vc2015\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\Microsoft.PythonTools.Debugger.Helper.x86.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'python_d.exe' (Python): Loaded ''. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x26d4 has exited with code 1577189376 (0x5e020000).
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'python_d.exe' (Python): Loaded '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'. Module was built without symbols.
AttributeError
Additional information: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

The stack:

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>!_spec_from_module Line 483    Python
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>!_setup Line 1107              Python
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>!_install Line 1134            Python
[External Code]
python_d.exe!wmain(int argc, wchar_t * * argv) Line 14        C
[External Code]
```

I was able to debug into the Python code (at least to look at the Visual Studio *Locals*). We need to be able to debug in the Python and native code. This is what the stack looks like after the failure:

[Mixed Use Call Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43pcc.jpg)

This is the Python function that fails (with the code as far the point of failure):

```
def _spec_from_module(module, loader=None, origin=None):
    # This function is meant for use in _setup().
    try:
        spec = module.__spec__
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    else:
        if spec is not None:
            return spec
    name = module.__name__
    if loader is None:
        try:
            loader = module.__loader__
        except AttributeError:
            # loader will stay None.
            pass
    try:
        location = module.__file__
```

But there is no `__file__` field in module:

[Contents of module object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVE13.jpg)

The loader object has many fields, but here are some of them:

```
loader    has type class BuiltinImporter
loader.__module__'_frozen_importlib'                str
loader.__mro__     (<class 'BuiltinImporter'>, <class 'object'>)    tuple
```

Comment: You might want to detail, at the start of the question, what is the question you are having... [also, read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I got the debug version to work as follows:

Reinstall Quantlib 1.6.2 and Quantlib SWIG 1.6.1

Build Quantlib and Quantlib SWIG in Debug mode.

Then I still had a startup error, but it was more obvious that it was looking at a different version of Quantlib.py.

I deleted the contents of the VirtualStore:
`\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\Lib\site-packages\QuantLib\`